# How do I exclude a particular number with a regular expression？

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I exclude a particular number with a regular expression ？I want to use regular expressions to match the **0-9999** direct digits.It keep **two decimal places at most** and it can contain 0 and 9999 but not **'9999.xx'** and not **'10.xxx'**.

I tried to write a regular expression as follows, But it contains 9999.xx. I expect to exclude '**9999.xx**'.Can someone help me change this regex ?

```
let reg = /^([1-9]{1}\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?|0(\.\d{1,2}){0,1})$/

reg.test(0)        #outputs true
reg.test(000)      #outputs false
reg.test(9999)     #outputs true
reg.test(0.11)     #outputs true
reg.test(0.111)    #outputs false
reg.test(0.1111)   #outputs false
reg.test(9999.)    #outputs false
reg.test(9999.00)  #outputs true


reg.test(9999.01)  #outputs true
```

I expect the output of /^([1-9]{1}\d{0,3}(.\d{1,2})?|0(.\d{1,2}){0,1})$/.test(9999.01) to be false, but the actual output is true

Comment: Do you want to make sure that the number is no greater than 9999? Or are you trying to exclude a particular decimal combination?

Comment: I want to just type in Numbers between 0 and 9999，and it can enter two decimal places

Comment: Why not just use if ( num >= 0 && num  <= 9999 ) instead of regex ?

Comment: @Code Maniac No, It It must use a regular. and  it can enter two decimal places

Comment: @huaLin it need to strictly two decimal digits only ? but i don't see a need of regex here

Comment: This seems needlessly restrictive, probably homework. 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @huaLin will `9999.00` is to be included or excluded ?

Answer (score 2):

You could negative lookahead for `9999\.\d` at the beginning of the pattern:

```
^(?!9999.\d)(?:[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/3FvU2a/1

Note that `{0,1}` simplifies to `?`, and you can combine the numbers in the right of the decimal into a single group to make the pattern more DRY. You may also remove `{1}` (a token will by default match exactly once, after all).

Comment: Your regex can't rule out ‘000’ and ‘9999.’ , Can you make a change？

Comment: it test(9999.) also have return true.  it test(0) can be true , but it test(000) should be exclude.

Comment: 9999 can,  but  9999.  can't

Comment: Are you even running @CertainPerformance's regex? It's doing exactly what you requested: `0` and `9999` match; neither `9999.` nor `000` match

Comment: Yep, they seem to match (or not match) as desired. Also, use code blocks, eg `9999.` so each character in code can be seen easily :)

Comment: Here's a slightly less efficient version that doesn't use negative lookahead (e.g. if you need to run this regex with Golang): `^(?:[1-8]\d{0,3}|9\d{0,2}|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^9999$|^0$`

Comment: @CertainPerformance  @ eddies
/^(?:[1-8]\d{0,3}|9\d{0,2}|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^9999$|^0$/.test(9999.),  return true.

/^(?:[1-8]\d{0,3}|9\d{0,2}|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^9999$|^0$/.test(000),   return true.

so the  regex can't  match me

Comment: @huaLin You should pass a *string* to `.test`, not a number. `/^(?:[1-8]\d{0,3}|9\d{0,2}|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^9999$|^0$/.test('9999.') === false` and `/^(?:[1-8]\d{0,3}|9\d{0,2}|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^9999$|^0$/.test('000') === false`

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you only need a range check here:

```
var number = 9999;
if (number >= 0 && number <= 9999) {
    console.log("match");
}
```

You might also want to check that the input is a valid number first, using `isNaN()`:

```
var number = "9999";
if (!isNaN(number) && number >= 0 && number <= 9999) {
    console.log("match");
}
```

Comment: No, It It must use a regular

Comment: only up to 2 decimal digits, your answer will approve more.

Comment: Well I don't like using regex here, and unless you have some assignment which is requiring it, I would use my answer.

Comment: @AZ_ That's a bit of a meaningless thing for an actual number in JavaScript, because floating point arithmetic is not exact anyway.

Comment: It keep two decimal places at most. Something like a 3-digit decimal is also excluded.  100.111  should be  excluded